# Using String.format to remove particular digits from an integer

Tags: java, string, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting

Say we have a number

```
int number = 1234
```

and I want to use formatting to extract the final two digits as a string `34`. How can one accomplish that?

I attempted:

```
String extraction = String.format("%d", number)
```

but this simply copies the entire number. I'm new to the syntax used by the formatter and can't seem to figure out the syntax that can go inside the characters of a number (or a String, for that matter) and pull them out. I've found a solution using `charAt` methods but am particularly curious about whether it's possible to accomplish it using formatting techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going via a `String` is inefficient and unnecessary to extract the last two digits of an integer.

Simply:

```
int lastTwoDigits = number % 100;
```

If you *do* want to go via a `String`, you can use:

```
String s = Integer.toString(number);
s = s.substring(s.length() - 2);
int lastTwoDigits = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

(note that this handles -ve numbers slightly differently to the first suggestion).

Comment: does the `String`approach assume that the number is a positive integer greater than `10` ?

Comment: The concept of "the last two digits of a number" only really makes sense if that number has at least two digits. And handling of negative numbers isn't defined. These are really cases which should be left up to OP to decide how they should be handled.

Comment: Thank you. it seems to me that it is not possible using formatting techniques to extract certain parts of strings/integers